# Can I create a Hive table from a file like we do in MySQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Can I create a Hive table from a sql/text file like we do in the case of MySQL and other RDBMSs. That is, store the "create table..." command in a .sql file and execute it in one go.

For eg. in MySQL I can do this

> shell> mysql < sql_file

or if you are already running mysql,

> mysql> source sql_file

1) Is there any such option in Hive

2) If yes, what would be the command and what would be the file extension

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -f /home/my/hive-script.sql from terminal. Refer to hive documentation link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli .

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a scirpt in a file with .sql extension. Like HiveScript.sql
2. Ensure that hive is working properly by using hive command and see whether hive shell is open or not.
3. Run hive -f HiveScript.sql

Comment: add more details to your answer

Comment: Could you be more specific what you want?

Comment: you are giving an answer to a question asked 5 years ago and the answer to this question is accepted already. so the only reason to add another answer is to make it more clear for someone who doses not understand the original answer.